# Waitpid acting as if in non-blocking mode

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls, pid, waitpid

I am playing around with system calls in C and I am stuck trying to understand this program I made -

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int a;
char *args[]={"sleep"," 10",NULL}; 

a = fork();
int stat;


if(a==0){
    setpgid(getpid(),getpid());
    printf("%d\n",getpgid(getpid()));
    execvp(args[0],args);}
else
{
    int t2;
    waitpid(-a,&t2,0);
}

printf("Parent pid = %d\n", getpid()); 
printf("Child pid = %d\n", a); 

}
```

According to my understanding, I have set pgid of child as its own pid. When I call `waitpid` with -a as argument, I am basically asking it to wait(blocking) till any process in pgid=a is finished. However, the output of the program is not what I expected! Child process isn't being reaped at all. It is as if waitpid is in non-blocking mode. Output:

```
Parent pid = 11372
Child pid = 11373
11373
```

(The output is instantaneous, it doesn't wait for 10 seconds!)

EDIT : I added `printf("Here")` and `exit(1)` below execvp and printed out waitpid's output as suggested in comments. Here doesn't get printed and waitpid prints -1

Comment: Are you sure your exec() call succeed? Add a call to exit(1); just after, in the case it fails...

Comment: First of all check what `waitpid` *returns*. And if it returns zero then check the value of `t2` to learn the exit code of the child process. And don't forget to check if `execvp` returns as well.

Comment: I tried doing as you both suggested. Control flow doesn't go below execvp and waitpid is returning -1.

Comment: If `waitpid()` is returning -1, you should print out `errno` to see why it's failing (`perror()` or `strerror()` can be used to get a human readable error message instead of a cryptic number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a race condition. After the fork here:

```
a = fork();
```

if the child runs first the process group `-a` is created here:

```
if(a==0){
    setpgid(getpid(),getpid());
```

and the parent then waits here:

```
waitpid(-a,&t2,0);
```

but if the *parent* gets to run first, the process group `-a` does *not* exist yet and the `waitpid()` fails with `ECHILD`. The second case obviously happens on your system.

You will have to find some way to make sure, that the`setpgid()` call in the child runs *before* the `waitpid()` call in the parent. The complex way are semaphores, the easy (hacky) way is a short delay, `usleep(1)` before the `waitpid()` will probably suffice.